# Why use unnecessary "from the director of" for famous directors on movie posters?

Tags: posters

In some movie posters, we have:

> from the director of film 1, film 2 and film 3

[image: Titanic poster]

Which I can understand for non-famous directors. But why would that be necessary for directors well-known by the public as Christopher Nolan, Tim Burton or James Cameron, whose names are already guaranteed to make the film successful?

Comment: Not for everyone, some people still don't remember the director name but do remember there past films.

Comment: @AnkitSharma I still highly doubt that people tend to forgot Tim Burton's or James Cameron's name

Comment: I know people who don't remember director name and always say "ohhh is this film from the same director who made inception".

Comment: @AnkitSharma Alright, but not naming him at all (except for invisible yellow font down the poster) ? I find that as weird as not seeing Stephen King's name on one of his books. It will always be in big letters, even if "From the writer of Shining" might still be on the book cover.

Comment: "Yawn that film looks dead soppy.  What, wait - it was made by the guy who did Terminator and Aliens.... I love those films! Let's go see it."  Also - where is the directors name on that poster? It's small and difficult to read.

Answer (score 4):

My first reaction was "Cameron did 'True Lies'?". So that may be the thing, You may know the director and know he's famous. You may not know for what he's famous from.

Second thing is that all those movies are kinda action movies with shooting and futuristic gadgets. A things that was lacking in Titanic. So that would bring to cinemas people who like Terminator but may look at Leonardo and say "naaaah another chick-flick".

Also Cameron had only 5 movies under his belt that we consider "Hits" so the studio may feel that "Cameron is famous. For whom?" And the answer may be that not for the cinema goers who would like to watch 2 hours of people on a ship.
Edit: As Aliens are practically people on a ship. Cinema Goers who would like to watch romance movie.

Comment: Understandable for Titanic, but for Miss Peregrine's Home for Peculiar Children, the last Tim Burton's movie ? I don't think we can say Tim Burton wasn't "famous but for whom?" last year

Comment: Again, people may not know him by name. They may know his Burtonesque style connected to his "kid movies" and Miss Peregrine's, being a kids movie, don't have this style staple. Compare Miss P. posters with Alice in Wonderland one.

Comment: @sh5164 I think you're finding it difficult to get out of the 'movie fan' headspace.  Not everyone is a cinephile like you and I and, well, everyone on M&TV.  Some people just go to one or two movies a YEAR.  I know; it's difficult to believe (I'm at 136 so far this year). The marketing folks want to get at those people, so they go for the lowest common denominator: the titles of popular films.

Answer (score 1):

Poster is the first impression of movie where you don't know much about the product, Mostly directors have a constant theme or style among their movies.

Poster displays lead actors and a story element or background of movie-plot. Director's name and his last movies give theme to that movie,connects all dots.
So we do know what to expect from this movie.
Like in this case with lead-actors and ship with name of M. Night Shyamalan and his movie crono, you are going to expect something scary.

So in past when promotions were not used to be grand like these days, This thing was fundamental for the first interaction with a movie.